# combine two array's keys on a large dataset

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 26
            [hold_amount] => null
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 54
            [hold_amount] => null
        )
)
```

I have another array : -

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount_to_settle] => 15.04
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 26
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount_to_settle] => 45.53
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 54
        )

)
```

I need to combine the two such that I get a final array like this:

```
id
franchise_id
brand_id
hold_amount
amount_to_settle
```

How can it be done in an optimized way as the data set is huge

Comment: what is your desired output???

Comment: @MehulKuriya combine both the data set. and I've added the keys that I need in the final array

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map().

```
 $value = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
 print_r($value);
```

Here is reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

> You Can use Array Merge Function and to avoid std class obj error follow the format

```
$array1 = json_encode(json_decode(Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 26
            [hold_amount] => null
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 54
            [hold_amount] => null
        )
)));

$array2 = json_encode(json_decode(Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount_to_settle] => 15.04
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 26
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [amount_to_settle] => 45.53
            [franchise_id] => A123
            [brand_id] => 54
        )

)));

print_r(array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this is in a `foreach()` loop.

**Loop**

```
$newArray; //Store in here.


foreach($arrayOne as $k=>$v) {

    $key = array_search($v["brand_id"], array_column($arrayTwo, 'brand_id'));

    $newArray [] = [

        "id" => $v["id"], 
        "franchise_id" => $v["franchise_id"],
        "brand_id" => $v["brand_id"],
        "hold_amount" => $v["hold_amount"],
        "amount_to_settle" => $arrayTwo[$key]['amount_to_settle'],

    ] ;

}

var_dump($newArray);;
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {

    [0] => array(5) {
        ["id"] => int(1)
        ["franchise_id"] => string(4) "A123"
        ["brand_id"] => int(26)
        ["hold_amount"] => NULL
        ["amount_to_settle"] => float(15.04)

    }[1] => array(5) {

        ["id"] => int(2)
        ["franchise_id"] => string(4) "A123"
        ["brand_id"] => int(54)
        ["hold_amount"] => NULL
        ["amount_to_settle"] => float(45.53)

    }
}
```

**Edit:**

*Didnt realise your keys would be out of sync. It now uses `array_search()` and `array_column()` to match the value of `brand_id` from `$arrayOne` with `$arrayTwo`. It maybe worth adding in a condition to ensure it does not break if the match is not found but this will work despite count being out of sync.*

Comment: This will break if the two arrays don't have same count.

Comment: What relationship do they have? You did not mention a mismatch in count.

Comment: both the dataset will have brand_id and franchise_id. But, it may not have same count

Comment: See updated. It uses `array_search()` and `array_column()` to match the key `brand_id` with second array. It maybe worth adding in a condition to ensure it does not break if the match is not found but this will work despite count being out of sync.